# Dynamicly creating class with trait binding

Tags: php, class, eval, traits

I want to make use of traits in my project, and for multiple inheriance I want to use traits.

So I created some traits to use eg: tItem_Epic, tItem_Weapon, Item_Driver

When I create new class for Sword, I thought I could use eval to create class:

```
<?php
function new_item_class($type)
{
    eval('class Item_'.ucfirst($type).' extends Item_Driver { use tItem_Epic, tItem_Weapon; }');
}
?>
```

This is an example. There are some more parameters that change the course of eval (like: item quality, etc.).

Does this slow down the progress? Or should I create a file for every item type and call them when needed? which one will be faster?

Comment: Traits is not multiple inheritance. It's compiler based copy and paste. So what you do there (user-code execution based copy and paste making use of compiler based copy and paste) looks a bit over-complicated I must admit. Which does not mean something on it's own, just saying.

Comment: Yes I know how traits work. But in my project there will be too much posibilities for a sword and every posibility needs it's own methods. So creating a class on the fly, seemed right to me

Comment: Probably you can improve that with the design you have instead, but for that not much has shared with your question (and it's probably not what you want). For the technical aspect I've added an answer.

Comment: You may want to take a look at strategy pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate the files on disk which could be a benefit with IDEs as they can parse those files as well and it's less magic.

For PHP there is not much difference between `eval` (your code-exmaple) and `include` (example with files on disk). So do what pleases you I'd say.

I personally prefer files because it's more direct than those magic classes. And I would not look for "performance" reasons to decide that. The kind of performance you talk about is short-sighted as it remains undefined about which kind of performance you talk about and especially because you did not yet run into a bottleneck.

Comment: I know it was asked long time ago, but I think it might be still useful. A lot better solution is with include. Eval is dangerous in this case mostly because of no option of testing it. with include you can always just see file after compilation. You could also take a look on prototyping in php(like javascript). You can find different patterns in php on https://github.com/domnikl/DesignPatternsPHP.