# Dynamic use traits inside a class

Tags: php

I have this multiple traits

```
trait router{

    function router_name(){
        return 'home';
    }

}

trait database{

    function database_name(){
        return 'app';
    }

}

trait httpinput{

    function input_name(){
        return 'get';
    }

}
```

and this array of names of traits

```
$cofig['traits'] = ['router','database','httpinput'];
```

and a class where all traits will be use in

```
class testclass{

}
```

now, how can I dynamically declare the traits inside the class using the `$config` array

I know I can do,

```
class testclass{
    use router,database,httpinput;
}
```

but I want to embed those traits dynamically base on those values on the `$config` array e.g.

```
foreach($config as $c){
    use $c;
}
```

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355029/is-it-possible-to-add-traits-to-a-class-in-php-in-runtime

Comment: Defining classes gives your code predictable structure. Why does this have to happen dynamically?

Comment: If you, somehow, _would_ be able to make this work, you're setting yourself up for problems. If classes automatically change their definitions/API's, you won't be able to just look at a class to see what the API looks like. It will be a massive pain to debug and document your classes.

Comment: @deceze because traits by time will be added and removed, they store on a single and then I just include them

Comment: @MagnusEriksson just that one class will be used, no other classes

Comment: If only one class would have this, it would be even worse, since it would break consistency. Also, _why_ do you need this? It kind of sounds like a [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I want those trait available only from that class to my application

Comment: If the method declarions are dynamic, why not implement `__call` method?

Comment: How often do you add and remove traits that you need to dynamically figure them out *at runtime*…? I really think you’re trying to solve a non-issue here.

Comment: _"I want those trait available only from that class to my application"_ - Then why use traits? Just add the methods directly to your class. Also, if you want that class to do different things in different situations, how would you even _use_ that class since you won't know what methods exists in it? You should use different classes instead.